# Change all position of elements in List using Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am a fresher in Java. I just want to change  all position of elements in List using Java 8. For example:

```
public static List<Integer> change(List<Integer> data){
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        Collections.swap(data, i, data.size()-1-i);
    }
    return data;
}
```

this is a simple example, it just reverse the list. let me explain more : 
i have a list {1,3,4,5,3,7,8,9} >> and i want to change to {3,1,5,4,7,3,9,8}.

But I want to do it in Java 8(Stream). My problem is:

1) How can I get the next element in a stream ?

2) Can I put my own method when I traverse with stream? (for example,  I can write my own swap method?) - Like : list.foreach(doSomething());

3) And how can i return result when using foreach?

Comment: What do you mean by "changing all positions". In other words: what kind of transformation do you intend to apply? "change" says *nothing* about what exactly this method is supposed to do. If your english isnt good, then put up an **example** list; and show intial and final state; after swapping.

Comment: Btw there is also a `Collections.reverse`

Comment: This loop doesn't make any change to the `List`. In half iterations, it exchanges the elements which makes the list reversed. In another half iteration, It reverses the reversed list. So It gives the same original list at last.

Comment: `Collections.shuffle(data);`

Comment: A stream cann't be use to change the order of elements. The order that they go in is the order they go out, (unless it's undefined)

Comment: sorry, i have explained more , i just want to know how to get the next element in stream, and can i put my own method when using stream 
lijke : ... list.foreach(doSomething());

Comment: Just use the code you have. Using Java 8 doesn’t imply “doing everything with Stream”.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "1", "2", "3");

    // shuffle or randomize
    Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Comment: OP does not want to shuffle, want's to swap each pair?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shuffle in such a way that no item is where it was before then you can simply use

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

and then swap the 1st and the middle item if the length of the list is odd. This way all your items will be at a different index then they were before.

Answer (score 0):

If using streams is required

```
public static List<Integer> change2( List<Integer> data ) {

    return data.stream().collect( LinkedList::new, LinkedList::offerFirst, LinkedList::addAll );

}
```

The stream is reversed using a LinkedList to collect data ; offerFirst inserting next element in front.

Or with a custom function

```
final Random random = new Random();
return data.stream().collect(
    LinkedList::new,
    ( list, elem ) -> {
        int size = list.size();
        list.add( random.nextInt( size + 1 ), elem );
    },
    LinkedList::addAll
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "forEach" that Streams provide.
by saying "a->" you map each element of the data list to the "a" where is every element of the list

This is the best solution if you dont want just to shuffle them but do something more with each one of the elements of the list.

```
public static List<Integer> change(List<Integer> data){
    return data.stream().forEach(a-> "whatever you want to do with them").collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `peek` or `map` rather than `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to drive your list through an `IntStream` and swap elements within `forEach`:

```
public static List<Integer> change(List<Integer> data) {
    IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)
            .limit(data.size() / 2)
            .forEach(i -> Collections.swap(data, i, i + 1));
    return data;
}
```

You have to use `Stream.limit` so that the stream is not infinite.

However, using `Collections.swap` to mutate the list within `forEach` is discouraged because it has side-effects. If the `IntStream` were declared to be parallel, the code above would be broken. Ideally, the functions and consumers used in a stream should be stateless and without side-effects, as recommended in the [`java.util.stream` package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Here's another way to achieve what you want, while also adhering to recommendations:

```
public static List<Integer> changeCorrectly(List<Integer> data) {
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)
            .limit(data.size() / 2)
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(data.get(i + 1), data.get(i)))
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note: I'm using `IntStream.flatMap` to return an `IntStream` of swapped pairs, which has the effect to unbox `Integer` elements from the `data` list. Immediately, I'm boxing the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`.

The alternative to avoid this unboxing/boxing stuff is:

```
public static List<Integer> changeCorrectly(List<Integer> data) {
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)
            .limit(data.size() / 2)
            .mapToObj(i -> Stream.of(data.get(i + 1), data.get(i)))
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Final comment: this only works when the `data` list has an even size. Handling the addition of the last element when the `data` list has an odd size is left as an exercise.